# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Chrome application

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-app

A have a problem...

I create a request to the server. I need to download photo at URL, but 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin will not let me do it. Please, help me!

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET',"`http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-ash/t51.2885-15/925251_476615232484089_631852735_n.jpg`", true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
xhr.setRequestHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '`https://ipfmnlpkligplampkpahcmideefmcmpl.chromiumapp.org/`');
xhr.onload = function(e){
$("<img src='"+window.URL.createObjectURL(this.response)+"'>").append("body");
  };
xhr.send();
```

**Console:**

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load `http://scontent-a.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-ash/t51.2885-15/10362165_1441926822728933_946328003_n.jpg`. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'chrome-`extension://ipfmnlpkligplampkpahcmideefmcmpl`' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Comment: You are encountering the same-origin policy. As it's an image, you may be able to get away with using `<img>` directly

Comment: I'm understand you, you can read more?

Comment: Furthermore, idk if it's your copy/paste or in the real code, but you've got backticks in there.

Answer (score 1):

In a Chrome App, you don't need to worry about [cross-domain permissions in XHRs](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/xhr).

You need to make sure the resource you're loading is specified in permissions of the manifest.

P.S. Your workaround is not working, because you're setting request fields and the error is about response fields.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this all in [Vanilla](http://vanilla-js.com/) and directly with `<img>`.

```
(function (src) {
    var img = new Image(); // or document.createElement('img');
    function _load() {
        this.removeEventListener('load', _load);
        document.body.appendChild(this);
    }
    img.addEventListener('load', _load);
    img.src = src; // fetch
}('http://scontent-b.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-ash/t51.2885-15/925251_476615232484089_631852735_n.jpg'));
```

Comment: No,Chrome app can not download this, because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' data: chrome-extension-resource.
Should download img and paste in body.